# ASP.NET MVC3 RenderPage & Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've a problem with RenderPage together with Html.BeginForm (don't know what i'm doin wrong).

Suppose you have a simple _Test.cshtml such as this:

```
@{
    <span>Test Text</span>
}
```

Then suppose you have a simple page like this (wich uses _Test.cshtml):

```
 @{
    Layout = null;
    var b = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
}

@{
    <html>
        <body>
            @* @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Test.cshtml") *@
            <div>
                @foreach (int i in b)
                {
                    <div>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new { id = i }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frm_"+ i.ToString() })) 
                    {
                        <span>Label&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                        <input type="submit" id="@i.ToString()" value="@i.ToString()" />
                    }
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </body> 
    </html>   
}
```

If you comment out the RenderPage helper call you correctly get a series of form with the corresponding submit button. If you uncomment the RenderPage helper no  tag is generated. Don't know what's going on, may someone help me?

Comment: Why are you wrapping your page in code blocks?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using RenderPage? `Html.Partial` seems more native:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    var b = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
}
<html>
    <body>
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Test.cshtml")
        <div>
            @foreach (int i in b)
            {
                <div>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new { id = i }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frm_"+ i.ToString() })) 
                {
                    <span>Label&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <input type="submit" id="@i.ToString()" value="@i.ToString()" />
                }
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

and also your partial (no need of those server side bocks `@{}` when you have static HTML):

```
<span>Test Text</span>
```

Comment: I know, it was only to simplify at the best minimu the contents of the page.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug I think:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/652944/html-beginform-output-not-rendered-if-preceded-by-renderpage

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your _Test.cshtml to

```
<span>Test Text</span>
```

And this is probably a matter of taste but I prefer `Html.Partial` to `RenderPage`.

Comment: Yes, it's a matter of taste I agree, but anyway if you use RenderPage it doesn't work and I would like to know why.